# Converting from UTF-8 in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C++ library that generates some strings encoded using UTF-8. This library is consumed by a C# library that is able to access to the strings using a ddlexport.

The C# code creates an StringBuilder and the C++ fills the characters in this object. But the characters that are not ASCII are impossible to be retrieved correctly.

e.g: the string "ö" is encoded using two bytes with the codes 195 and 182, that corresponds with the codification of this character in UTF-8 ([0xC3 0xB6](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f6/index.htm)). If I create the same string in C#, it is encoded using one byte with the code 246 that also corresponds with the codification for this character in Windows.

I've tried to use the "Encoding.Convert" methods but I've been not able to convert the original string to the right encoded string.

I've tried to reproduce the issue with this fragment of code:

```
StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder(2);
str1.Append("ö");
Console.WriteLine(str1.ToString());

StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder(2);
str2.Append((char)246);
Console.WriteLine(str2.ToString());

// This is the StringBuilder that I get from the C++ code
StringBuilder str3 = new StringBuilder(2);
str3.Append((char)195);
str3.Append((char)182);
Console.WriteLine(str3.ToString());

byte[] bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str3.ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
```

The output of this program is:

```
ö
ö
Ã¶
?? // bytes is 63, 63
```

How is possible to convert the UTF-8 code 0xC3 0xB6 (or 195 182) in the Windows code 246?

EDIT:

I've solved the problem with the answer of Marc Gravell just converting my StringBuilder to an array of bytes. But I wonder if the method that I'm using to pass strings between C++ and C# is wrong:

The C++ code:

```
 __declspec(dllexport)void Competitor_getDescription(ICompetitor *competitor, char *buf) {
   strcpy(buf, competitor->getDescription().c_str());
 }
```

The C#:

```
 [DllImport(DLL)]
 private static extern void Competitor_getDescription(IntPtr obj, StringBuilder str);  
 public String GetDescription()
 {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(50);
    Competitor_getDescription(this.ptr, str);
    return str.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: 246 is not a 'Windows code' but the Unicode value.

Comment: `This is the StringBuilder that I get from the C++ code` - no it isn't. You are simply appending two characters. Please show us what exactly you are getting from your library and how you are treating it.

Comment: Better post the interop code etc.  UTF-8 is a stream encoding, you may have more succes by passing a `byte[]` from C++ to C# and then use UTF8.GetString()

Answer (score 7):

You write:

> the string "ö" is encoded using two bytes with the codes 195 and 182

but your code says:

```
str3.Append((char)195);
str3.Append((char)182);
```

These two concepts are **completely different**. Your C# adds two *code-points*, not two bytes. Those code-points only make sense when considered as unicode - you can't ask what the *bytes* are unless we define a specific encoding, but in terms of UTF-8, those correspond to the byte sequences 0xC3 0x83 and 0xC2 0xB6 respectively.

If you want to decode UTF-8, then: *decode UTF-8*:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 195, 182 };
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); // ö, code-point 246
```